# How to create a new Image() with an image file located in a directory outside the current working directory

Tags: image, javafx, imageview

I'm trying to list iamges in a TilePane. I get an error when I try to create an Image, `new ImageView("address");` with a address like so:

```
"file:D:/Chrysanthemum.jpeg/"
```

The above is in a directory outside the current working directory. The other images are inside the class path.

Here's the rest of the code in an scec:

```
public class TilePaneExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        VBox root = new VBox(30);

        String[] imageResources = new String[]{
            //loading images
            "file:D:/Chrysanthemum.jpeg/",
            "ImageResources/faviicon.png",
            "ImageResources/jquery-logo.png",
            "ImageResources/linkedin_32.png",
            "ImageResources/loading1.png",
            "ImageResources/twitter.png",
            "ImageResources/twitter_32.png",
            "ImageResources/wp.png",};

        // Pane
        TilePane tilePane = new TilePane();
        tilePane.setHgap(5);
        tilePane.setVgap(5);

        for (final String imageResource : imageResources) {
            Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(imageResource));
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
            imageView.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                    File f = new File(imageResource);
                    String absolutePath = f.getAbsolutePath();
                    String folderPath = absolutePath.
                            substring(0, absolutePath.lastIndexOf(File.separator));
                    System.out.println(folderPath);
                    try {
                        // Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("D:\\WAKILI\\WAKILIdb"));
                        Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(folderPath));
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
                        System.out.println("File Not Found");
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(TilePaneExample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            });
            tilePane.getChildren().add(imageView);
        }

        root.getChildren().addAll(tilePane);
        primaryStage.setTitle("TilePane Example");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 150);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Input stream must not be null
```

Please help. Thank you all.

Comment: so, do you wanna to distribute this app somehow? how it will find this resource later?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using getClass().getResourceAsStream(imageResource) even for your none classpath images, pass the URL-String directly for cases you are not loading from the classpath:

```
Image image;
if(imageResource.startsWith("file:")) {
  image = new Image(imageResource);
} else {
  image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(imageResource));
}
```